# supplying 'id' to the child 'list'(li) of the unorder list (ul) in codeigniter

Tags: php, html

normally in HTML we supply ID and class to the li of the ul is as shown below

```
<html>
      <head>
      </head>
  <body>
     <ul id="ul" class="ul_class">
          <li id="list1"> List 1 </li>
          <li id="list2"> List 2 </li>
          <li id="list3"> List 3 </li>
     </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

but i am struck in codeigniter,how to supply id and class to the li of ul 
in codeigniter.This is what i tried below.

in 'view' page

```
<?php


 $this->load->helper('html'); //loaded html helper

$list = arrray(
                'list1',
                'list2',
                'list3'
              );


 $attributes =   array(
                       'id' => 'ul',
                           'class' => 'ul_class'
                 );
echo ul($list,$attributes);

     ?>
```

i got the output like this

```
  <ul id='ul' class='ul_class'>
     <li> List 1 </li>
     <li> List 2 </li>
     <li> List 3 </li>
    </ul>
```

although i referred to the codeigniter user_guide,there they given only for supplying id and class to ul not for li..now my question is how to supply 'id' or 'class' to the LI of UL in codeigniter ?

Comment: not sure if this is a copy and paste error but you have spelt array wrong: `$list = arrray`

Comment: Check this out http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/110356/#556633